# Replicant in QEMU virtual machine

Tags: custom-roms, virtualization

I need an Android virtual machine to run an app I don't want to install in my device. I managed to install Android-x86 in QEMU, but I'd like to use Replicant instead. So, the question is: is it possible to install Replicant in a virtual machine with QEMU?

Please consider that I have nearly no experience in virtualizing Android and I have never used Replicant before.

Comment: Based on their [supported devices](https://replicant.us/supported-devices.php), Replicant doesn't seem to provide Android for PC/Virtualization, so I'm afraid what you want is not possible now...

Comment: What is wrong with the standard Android Emulators provided by Google (Android SDK) or those that come pre-installed like Genymotion? Those emulators are well adapted to their run-time environment which makes them run much better than any custom Android-X86 installation.

Comment: @Robert I'm not using Android SDK because I prefer to avoid Google products as much as possible, but I might consider it if I can't find any other solution. About Genymotion and other emulators, I have a personal rule to use only free software on my device and I couldn't find a free Android emulator.